# How to repeat class after 3rd div?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add different class on first 3 divs. and then repeat the class again. For example, first div class on 4th div and 2 div class on 5th div and so on.

```
foreach($val as $myval)
{
?>
    <div><?php $myval['name'] ?></div>
<?php   
}
```

This is my html.

```
<div class="container first-div">
    <div class="main_head col-lg-6">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <div class="take-right"> How to improve your skills. </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container second-div">
    <div class="main_head col-sm-12">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container third-div">
    <div class="main_head col-lg-5">
    <span>Here Are Just A Testing Content</span>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container first-div">
    <div class="main_head col-lg-6">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container second-div">
    <div class="main_head col-sm-12">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container third-div">
    <div class="main_head col-lg-5">
    <span>Here Are Just A Testing Content</span>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
    </div>
</div>
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please post the expected HTML codes you want as well, by updating the question.

Comment: If you mean you want to add a class every n iterations, then you need to learn about modulus (the % operator in PHP)

Comment: You should post the css for `.first-div`, `.second-div` and `.third-div`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$classes = array('class1','class2','class3'); /* Create three class */
$cnt = 0; /* Create dummy counter */
foreach($val as $myval)
{  
   if($cnt == 3) $cnt = 0;
  ?>
   <div class="<?php echo $classes[$cnt];?>" ><?php $myval['name'] ?></div>
  <?php 
  $cnt++;  
}
```

Comment: Or just use modulous.  `(if ++$cnt % 3 === 0) {}`

Comment: I have different html for first 3 div's.

Comment: @php_dev So add all `html element` in `array` and use `foreach()` loop.

Comment: then how i will make the content dynamic into div's.

Comment: For now from where you are getting content ..?

Comment: @php_dev if agree with Wavemaster than don't use foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about css [`nth-child()`](http://nthmaster.com/) for styling every third element?

You can add as much styling as you want in the css.

```css
.container:nth-child(1n) {
  background: blue;
}
.container:nth-child(2n) {
  background: red;
}
.container:nth-child(3n) {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container first-div">
  <div class="main_head col-lg-6">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <div class="take-right">How to improve your skills.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container second-div">
  <div class="main_head col-sm-12">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container third-div">
  <div class="main_head col-lg-5">
    <span>Here Are Just A Testing Content</span>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container first-div">
  <div class="main_head col-lg-6">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container second-div">
  <div class="main_head col-sm-12">
    <h3>Here Are Just A Testing Content</h3>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container third-div">
  <div class="main_head col-lg-5">
    <span>Here Are Just A Testing Content</span>
    <h4> How to improve your skills. </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use html as dynamic there can be multiple divs. for first 3 divs i have different html

Comment: So please add your significant HTML to your question. The HTML you posted doesn't seem to have "different HTML". Even better: Try to explain exactly what you want as a result. I've just learned about the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have changed the html above. Please check.

Comment: I've updated the HTML in my answer. The result is still the same. Are you sure you need those classes? Wouldn't it be better to move the content of `.first-div` to `.container:nth-child(1n)`?

Comment: But in my html i have already added classes. Is is not possible with PHP loop?

Comment: Have you tried my proposed solution? It doesn't matter if you have already classes you can add `nth-child()` nevertheless. Are your requested classes for styling only?